# Subfootnotes with bigfoot package

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

How can i make subfootnotes (like in ConTeXt) with bigfoot package.

I making a copy of book in Latex. Footnotes there have two levels. On top level they labaled with numbers number 99, 100 etc. On second level the label is a current footnote plus letter counter (100, 100a, 100b, 101).

Sample page:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it creating new counter and defining new command:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{default}

\newcounter{footalt}[footnote]
\def\thefootalt{\thefootnote \alph{footalt}}
\def\footnoteA{\refstepcounter{footalt}%
   \Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}

\begin{document}
Hello.\footnote{usual footnote} This\footnote{second usual footnote} is a
test.\footnoteA{ sub footnote}
This is a test.\footnoteA{ sub footnote} This is a test. This is a test.

\end{document}
```

[image]