# Removing space between heterogenous bigfoot notes

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, bigfoot

How do I remove the extra space between numeric and
alphabetic notes?  And how do I make them appear in the order in which
they were written?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\textheight=1.5in

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]

\begin{document}

foo\footnote{tnote}
bar\footnote{tholomew}
baz\footnoteA{ooka}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inspired / from in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424311/161015

No extra space and in order of appearance.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\textheight=1.5in

\DeclareNewFootnote{default}

\newcounter{footnotenew}[footnote]
\renewcommand{\thefootnotenew}{\alph{footnotenew}}

\newcommand{\footnoteA}{%
    \stepcounter{footnotenew}%
    \Footnotedefault{\thefootnotenew}}

\begin{document}

foo\footnote{tnote}
bar\footnote{tholomew}
baz\footnoteA{ooka}

\end{document}
```